# C++ -- Array of different types of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

I'm new to C++ classes, and I'm trying to figure out how to make an array of different types of objects with a template. In this example, I'm trying to add seven Apple objects of weight 0.5 to the Basket array.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class DT> class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    virtual ~Object();
}
Object::Object() {}
Object::~Object() {}

class Apples
{
public:
    double weight;

    Apples(double apples);
    virtual ~Apples();
}
Apples::Apples(double weight)
{
    weight = weight;
}
Apples::~Apples() {}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Object* Basket[10];
    Apples* anApple;

    int position;
    position = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
        Basket[position + 1] = new Apple(0.5);

    return 0;
}
```

The main error I have is that I can't convert Object* to Apple* on the fourth line from the bottom. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where are you learning this stuff from? Wherever it is, learn it from somewhere else.

Comment: First decide what do you mean by Object<classDT>

Comment: Along with what @WhiZTiM noted, you'll later wonder why only `Basket[1]` has an `Apple`. You should use `i` as the index rather than `position` since you never change `position`.

Comment: have you tried a cast?

Comment: @PaulRooney what's wrong with my comment? to me it needs a cast to put an apple pointer in an array of object pointers. the error mentioned in the post may be related to it.

Comment: @Shiping It's not java. `Apples` is not implicitly a subclass of `Object`. So if you cast it you are basically strong arming the compiler to make it think its a type that it isn't. The compiler would force you to use `reinterpret_cast`, which should make alarm bells ring.

Comment: @PaulRooney i didn't say or assume it's java. i'm not judging if his program would run correctly or make sense to put apples in an array of objects (surely sometimes you do assign pointers to one kind of variables to pointers of other variables), but i just tried to help find out the cause of the error.

Comment: @Shiping apologies for my original comment, it could have been more constructive. But trust me that is not the way to fix it.

Comment: @PaulRooney agree with you about fixing the entire program. but i believe casting would make that error go away (but again here I agree with you that it may or may not mean that's correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `Apples` inherit from `Object`:

```
class Apples : public Object
```

And there is no need for `Object` to be a template here.

Other things:

- Don't store the objects in an uninitialized array. You won't be able to determine which slots are initialized and which not later on. Either reset all pointers to null first or better use an `std::vector`.
- The positioning logic seems wrong. You don't use `i`, but always store at `position+1`, which is always 1. Indexing starts at 0, so you probably just want `i` here.
- Think about how you can safely delete the objects later on. Either you need to iterate over the array and call `delete` on every object. Or you might think about using `std::vector<unique_ptr<Object>>`.